# Why is it not suggested to implement typeahead using Wildcard search?

Tags: solr

Normally a majority of tutorials either suggest implementing autosuggest, either using Suggester component or primitive typehead techniques:

https://blog.griddynamics.com/implementing-autocomplete-with-solr/

However my question is why no one suggests using simple wildcard search for this like for giving name suggestions when user types mob:

```
q=name:(*mob*)
```

Is it feasible to use this approach for implementing autosuggest against other approaches?What will be the repercussions?

Answer (score 2):

The strategy can work - for simple queries. The problem is that when you're querying with wildcards, the analysis chain is not invoked (a bit of a simplification - most filters are not invoked, only those that are MultiTermAware) - so as soon as you type a space, you're out of luck. You can work around this with the ComplexPhraseQuery, but that might not be what you're looking for (and can get expensive in regards to the number of terms quickly).

In your example with a leading wildcard, the query will also be very expensive - since it will require Lucene (Solr's underlying search library) to in effect look at each generated token and see if somewhere inside that token there's the text `mob`. And since you don't have any analysis taking place - if you'd have indexed `men's` (which would be processed to match just `men` as a single token in most cases), and searched for `men's*` - you wouldn't get a hit.

So it works - kind of - but it's not ideal. That's the reason why the suggester was implemented. The [suggester component supports many different configuration options](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_3/suggester.html) to get the behavior you want, as well as (for some backends) context filtering (which would be easier to implement with just a wildcard, since it'd be a regular `fq`). The suggester also supports weights - while wildcards wouldn't really do that in a proper way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.However I tried replacing space with backlash space and it seemed to work for most.

Comment: That depends on what kind of analysis has taken place on the input text to generate the tokens.